# Syntax for module option

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to make a type with an optional map:

```
module CharMap = Map.Make(Char)
type trie = bool * CharMap.t option
```

But this results in a syntax error:

```
Error: The type constructor CharMap.t expects 1 argument(s),
       but is here applied to 0 argument(s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CharMap.t` is a map from `char` to `'a`, so actually its type is `'a Charmap.t`, so you forget to specify the polymorphic argument. So you should write:

```
type 'a trie = bool * 'a CharMap.t option
```

If you want your map to be monomorphic (for instance `char -> int`) you can just write:

```
type trie = bool * int CharMap.t option
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to specify what 'a must be?